# WPF button position dependent on another element

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, data-binding

I would like to place my button always on the middle of the bottom frame of `ScrollViewer`. I am going to change both the size of window, and a size of `ScrollViewer`, but I want my button to be always as on the pictures.

[image]
Owing to the fact that i am following MVVM, I have just xaml. Basically, I would like to bind (live) the button top position from the pattern:

```
button.top = (scrollViewer.top + scrollViewer.height) - button.height/2
```

I would be grateful for your suggestions.

[EDIT] I forgot to add that all other controls are in grid rows and columns.

Comment: Setting button.top in code-behind won't break MVVM in any way.

Comment: Is it allways the same `ScrollViewer` - where your `Button` gets placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Grid` to achieve that. If you need to change the `ScrollViewer` size, just change `ScrollGrid` Grid size instead. To overlap bottom or top content, you can use negative margins for the button.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Red"/>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Grid x:Name="ScrollGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer></ScrollViewer>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is much simpler than I thought. It works with Storyboard as well.